# Snow in the end of November on the Mont Blanc Tunnel?

Tags: transit, france, snow

I'm planning a travel in the end of November and I want to pass through the Mont Blanc Tunnel, beginning in Chamonix until Aosta.
In this epoch of the year is it common to snow up coming to the tunnel?

Comment: http://www.chamonix.com/weather,11,en.html